# Launch a URI from a WPF app packaged as a Store app

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I have a C# WPF app that I currently deploy via .msi file (as a direct download from my website)

I now want to package the app up into an .appx and deliver it via the MS AppStore (in addition to my current direct download .msi option.)

I've got it all packaged up using the new VS2017 'Windows Application Packaging Project' and it pretty much works :-)

Problem I have is that my app attempts to 'launch' URLs (web links and paths to files.) Currently I do this using Process.Start() and it works well - but the docs imply this is not allowed in Store apps (especially on Windows10s)

Seems I should use Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync instead. But this API is only available to 'proper' UWP apps.

Anyone got any ideas on how to square this circle? Creating 2 apps and sharing code is not an option (I don't want to be on the store that badly!!)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is allowed.

The thing you can't do is call Process.Start() on an EXE that you have downloaded dynamically (i.e. not from your package). If you are not doing that you will be fine.

If the docs are confusing please share a pointer so I can get those fixed.

Comment: When I run the app certification tool I get
FAILED
File MYAPP\MYAPP.exe contains a reference to a "Launch Process" related API System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
Impact if not fixed: Launching executable files is restricted on Windows 10 S systems. Apps that rely on this capability might not run correctly on Windows 10 S systems.

Comment: This is an optional test. It won't block your Store submission. If you are not launching dynamically downloaded binaries you will be fine. I agree the test and error message can be confusing.